# Using Magific Popup

Tags: visualforce, jquery

Using [Magnific plugin](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) to try to display images in a lightbox gallery. 
Using `{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, someId)}` or `/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!someId}` instead of the filepath, just opens the file instead of showing in the lightbox.

So am wondering if anyone knows how I can get the same functionality.

How it's supposed to be:

```
<li><a href="./images/image01.jpg"><img src="./images/thumb01.jpg" oncontextmenu="return false;" /></a></li>
```

How I have to do it on salesforce:

```
<li>
  <a href="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!image01}">
    <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!thumb01!=''}">
      <img src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, thumb01)}" oncontextmenu="return false;" />
    </apex:outputpanel>
  </a>
</li>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the [Magnific documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html), you have to add a CSS class for each link where you want to have this functionality.

```
<a class="test-popup-link" href="path-to-image.jpg...
```

Then, you have to attach the magnificPopup function to each of the above links dynamically on page load.

```
$('.test-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type: 'image'
  // other options
});
```

Here is an example with complete code.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css"/>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready(function(){
            j$('.test-popup-link').magnificPopup({
              type: 'image'
              // other options
            });
         });
    </script>    

    <!--Here you have to use the Large image-->
    <a class="test-popup-link" href="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, '00P0H000014v63z')}">
        <!--Here you have to use the Thumbnail image-->
        <img src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, '00P0H000014v63z')}" width="100" height="100"/>
    </a>
</apex:page>
```

Screen Capture

[image]

Comment: D'oh! Thanx! (Also realized the <includeScript> was acting weird so linked to CDN file)